# How to save vector<vector<vector<float> > > in a file and retrieve data?

Tags: c++, boost

I need to save the content of a `vector<vector<vector<float> > >` into a file and then retrieve all values at the correct position.

Suggestions?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you would like to accomplish, can you give us some more details?

Comment: Every `vector` stores a size and an array of its contents.  If you can find a way to save a `vector<float>`, you're only two levels of indirection away.

Comment: I will try to protobuf!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, thank you

```
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/export.hpp> 
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/list.hpp>

void saveFeaturesFile(vector<vector<vector<float> > > &features, string filename){ 
    ofstream out(filename.c_str());
    stringstream ss;
    boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(ss); 
    oa << features;
    out << ss.str();
    out.close();    
}

void loadFeaturesFile(vector<vector<vector<float> > > &features, string filename){
    ifstream in(filename.c_str());
    boost::archive::binary_iarchive ia(in); 
    ia >> features;    
    in.close();
}
```

and linked 
    -lboost_iostreams -lboost_serialization

Comment: Please keep in mind that the binary archive, although much faster than text or xml, is not portable between different cpu architectures (big/little endian). I don't know if that's an issue for you, but just as a sidenote.

Comment: yes, I know, but I really need it fast :) thank you

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at boost  serialization library.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it by yourself, you could do something like this:

```
std::ofstream file("floats.bin", std::ios::binary);
std::vector<float> f;
std::size_t n = f.size();

// save the size of the vector so you know how much to read
// when you load from file

file.write( reinterpret_cast<char*>( &n ), sizeof(n) );

// write the data

file.write( reinterpret_cast<char*>( f.data() ), sizeof(float) * n );
```

You'd need to do this for every inner vector. It's up to you to decide on exact details of the file format. Do take varying sizes of data types into account, though.

To read the data back, you'd first read the size information, resize a vector accordingly and then do [ifstream::read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read).

Answer (score 1):

You could write it out to a binary file in bytes.  Then when you read it back in you could read it back into a char array and cast it to your type.

Check out http://courses.cs.vt.edu/cs2604/fall02/binio.html